# Why does ASP.NET control value change take 2 postback to show up?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a lot of ASP.NET control in a forum.  If I change the value in my browser and postback.  It take 2 postback to have it show up in C#, why is this?

Comment: You must provide more details to get any help here.  You don't show what the ASP.NET control looks like, code for the client or server or anything.  For all we know it checks a static variable to ensure it has been posted back more than once to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you saving the value before the repopulating your controls? If not, your controls probably show stale values, after which you save, so its not until the *second* postback and subsequent render that you see the changes.

Comment: YOU are absolutely right!  This is exactly what is happening, but it's repopulating the control after Page_Load.  Which is too late (and I have to wait until second postback to see it).  How do I seee it on the first postback's Page_Load?

Comment: Generally you restore from ViewState, so you initial populating code should be wrapped in a check for !Page.IsPostBack.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure to call your Binding method again after saving the changes? If not, your page is posting back, but using the original ViewState that it had before you saved the changes. A typical process looks something like this.

```
// In your page load
if (!Page.IsPostBack())
{
   BindData();   // This calls the binding method the first time you hit the page.
}

// In your button click event
if (Page.IsValid())
{
   UpdateData();
   BindData();   // If you don't call this method, you'll post back, but not rebind.
}

// In your BindData method
txtThis.Text = data.this;
txtThat.Text = data.that;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was reloading the control on event, which refresh the data before it hit the Page_Load.